# Проблема с вводом пароля в Linux

Tags: linux

Искал в интернете, нашёл несколько вариантов решения проблемы, но безуспешно.

При запуске Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.0 32 bit запрашивался пароль, чего раньше не было.

После ввода этого пароля мелькает чёрный экран и опять перебрасывает на ввод пароля.

Я зашёл в консоль, удалил пароль, ещё мне приходилось приписывать `PATH:/usr/bin` так как команды не выполнялись.

Затем я пробовал обновлять пакеты, в конце концов помогла команда `strace -f -o /tmp/x.log startx`, также пробовал удалить 2 скрытых файла.

После этой команды я вошёл в линукс, но после перезагрузки опять запрос пароля, пришлось снова входить в терминал выполнять команды.

Что делать? Пожалуйста подскажите что-нибудь

Answer (score 0):

Не всегда существуют какие-то общие решения.В интернете найти решения не удалось.

**Вся ошибка была из-за переменной PATH**,которую нужно было прописать в `/etc/profile.` 
Вот так она должна была выглядеть:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Проблема в том, что я установил JDK 8, вернее, поменял JDK 11 на JDK 8, и переменная **PATH** сбилась.

Решение такое : **надо добавить вышеуказанную строчку через двоеточие.**

Comment: Ни в коем случае не трогайте системные настройки, если точно не представляете, что делаете!